# Send email of different template in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, magento-community

I am getting mail content as `object` instead of `HTML` content... 
Here is my `Magento Code`

```
//mail
$this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
$this->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');

//get customer details
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer->getId();  
$customer->getEmail();  

//get general store details
$from_name = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');
$from_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
$templateId = 7;        // My Email Template ID
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($templateId);

$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName($from_name);
$mail->setToEmail($from_email);
$mail->setBody($emailTemplate);
$mail->setSubject('Sample Mail Subject');
$mail->setFromEmail($customer->getEmail());
$mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
$mail->setType('Html');

try {
    $mail->send();
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');   
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
}
```

I want the `HTML` contents of the template as the output.

Please Help ! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to process your template.

```
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate();
........
.........
$mail->setBody($processedTemplate);
```

I haven't tested though. But should work.